# Calculating DDR4 DRAM Timing Parameters

Tags: ddr

If DDR4 runs at 1600Mhz, then how to calculate value of a parameter if its value is given as `Max(4nCK, 5ns)`?

I am assuming it means value of the parameter is whichever is greater - 4nCK or 5ns. Is this right?

I am confused as one value is in nCK and another is in ns.

At 1600Mhz, is not 1 nCK = 625ps? If that is right, then 4nCK is 2.5ns. Then is the value of the parameter 5ns?

OR

If 5ns = 8nCK (assuming my understanding of nCK = 625ps is right) then the value of the parameter is 8nCK.

I have googled and not able to find a guide or how to calculate DRAM parameters type of document.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the DRAM will always be operated at its rated clock speed (1600MHz for example). This is not necessarily the case. So if for some reason you only operate it at 500MHz, then in your example you're still bound by the 4nCK limit - resulting in 8ns instead of 5ns.